# Is there a way to not reset my C# program every time the player inputs something?

Tags: c#

Been working in this code for a couple days now trying to make minesweeper however, whenever I get input something the code reruns itself changing the position of the bombs (1). I have tried to narrow down the error and have come to the conclusion that it is reset on the ReadLine function. Couldn't find anything online.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MatrixProgram
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        var bomb_cords = new List<int>();
        int size = 9;
        int bombs = 6;
        string cord1;
        string cord2;
        int m = 1;
        int[,] arr1 = new int[size, size];
        
        //Setting up list for bomb cords
        for (int k = 0; k < bombs*2; k++){
            bomb_cords.Add(rnd.Next(0,size));
        }
        for (int l = 0; l < bomb_cords.Count/2; l++){
            arr1[bomb_cords[l],bomb_cords[m]] = 1;
            m++;
            
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("\n");
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                Console.Write("{0} ", arr1[i, j]);
        }
        //Get player input
        Console.Write("\n\n");
        Console.Write("Cord 1?(0-9) ");
        cord1 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Cord 2?(0-9) ");
        cord2 = Console.ReadLine();
        int cor1 = int.Parse(cord1);
        int cor2 = int.Parse(cord2);
        //Check if bomb
        if (arr1[cor1, cor2] == 1){
            Console.Write("DEAD");
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you all. I am sorry to say it was a simple compiling issue as I was using dotnet fiddle (an online editor) and it could'nt run it properly. as soon as I moved to VSC it worked fine.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree; the code as posted will simply ask the user for some input then check if it's a bomb and quit back to the command line (the app stops running). You'll then run the app again which will change the bombs. You need the app to satay running which means you need a loop around just the hit at the bottom where you ask for user input. That loop should run while there are moves to make and the player hasn't picked a bomb. Then you can quit the app with a well done/you died message

Comment: That doesn't really make any sense. The code here is essentially a Hello World: it runs, it prints, it asks, it exits. Are you running it in some online compiler like C# fiddle? If so, *don't*: how it's written is not compatible with those kind of websites, because they aren't interactive - they run your app til it asks for input, force quit the app, collect your input, then run the app again (new random bombs) and submit the input you provided.. Download Visual Studio and run it in that